# How to send image file in array object

Tags: arrays, file-upload, arrayobject

I am trying to send image file in array object with other details

services: [
{
service_type: 'service_type',
service_desc: 'service_desc',
service_image: 'service_iamge', // service_image is holding uploaded image file
}
{
service_type: 'service_type',
service_desc: 'service_desc',
service_image: 'service_iamge', // service_image is holding uploaded image file
}
{
service_type: 'service_type',
service_desc: 'service_desc',
service_image: 'service_iamge', // service_image is holding uploaded image file
}

```
    ],
```

this is basic array object i am trying to send to backend using ajax

i tried appending this array on FormData() but it is not working

then i tried json.stringify this array. In this i got service_type and service_desc after json_decode()  but i didn't got service image  it is showing {}

please help me how to get service_image in controller